# Computing how to extend an isomorphism to an automorphism on graphs

Tags: python, math, graph, igraph, combinatorics

My goal is to write a script which checks if it is possible if there is an extension from an isomorphism between two subgraphs of one graph, say G, to an automorphism on G.

Of course, this is not possible for all graphs, but take the cyclic graph or the graph of a standard simplex as an easy example where the subgraphs contains of some vertex and its neighbours with the connecting edges to them (this is called the star around that vertex).

Anyway, it tried implementing this using the iGraph package. Something like this:

```
import igraph as ig

def getStar(graph, initVertex):
    star = [initVertex]
    for i in graph.neighbors(initVertex):
        star.append(i)
    return star

g = ig.Graph(n=5, edges=[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [4,0])

sub_g = g.subgraph(getStar(g,0))
sub_g2 = g.subgraph(getStar(g,3))
```

But then i check for the isomorphisms between these two using

```
print(sub_g.get_subisomorphisms_vf2(sub_g2))
```

it yields in:

```
[[1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1]]
```

Visually, this means that the star gets mirrored along the 0-vertex.
For our example, this means that the blue subgraph (star around 0) gets fliped and embedded into the red subgraph (star around 3). See the illustration below.

[Cyclic 5-graph with the subgraphs in blue(#1) and in red(#2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85HFP.jpg)

(If needed, these are the automorphisms of g):

```
g.get_automorphisms_vf2()
```

gives:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 4, 3]
[2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 4]
[3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
[4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Problematic is that it the indexing of the vertices is getting reset to 0 and increments with each new vertex. Why do I need that? I thought about embedding the isomorphisms into  the automorphisms but for this the indexing should coincide. In the example above we would love to have the vertices 2,3 and 4.

Is there some way to fix the indexing. Or, is this even the right approach at all?
Or, is there some other idea to do tackle the overall problem?

Thanks for any help in advice!

Comment: Hi. This is an interesting problem. I understand the very first paragraph of your post. But then I'm completely lost with all the indices everywhere and I don't know how to interpret all the other things you said and the code and results you have shown.

Comment: Perhaps an actual drawing of the graph, with labels / indices on the vertices, could help explain the issue more visually

Comment: I have added a picture to the post

Comment: Regarding your brackets: A graph morphism is actually just defined by sending vertices to vertices.
So, for example, [[1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1]] can be viewed by sending 
vertex #1 to vertex #2,
vertex #0 to vertex #1 and
vertex #2 to vertex #1.
(I.e. this morphism mirrors the graph along the 0-vertex)
Does that clearify your confusion?

Comment: Don't put "EDIT: ..." in your post, just make the added information part of  your post's text as if it were there from the start. No one's tracking your post across all of 2 hours since you posted it. Answers (may!) need an "edit" heading when time has moved on, and months or even years later things have changed such that the answer is now technically a different answer, while preserving the original answer for folks still stuck in the past (programming wise). Posts _do not_ need edit heading, they're going to live forever and need to just read as [a single, complete post](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In your post you have `sub_g = ...; sub_g2 = ...` and then `print(sg.get_subisomorphisms_vf2(sg2))`. So there is a bit of an inconsistency in the names of the variables. Could this inconsistency be related to the issue?

Comment: Also when you write `sub_g = graph.subgraph(getStar(g,0))`, what is `graph`? Is that another name for `g`? Or for `igraph`?

Comment: You are right with your observations, they are are mistakes. i wanted to adept the names from my draft  for the sake of readability. I fixed them.